# Actionless URL produces HTTP 404 (Controller & Folder Name Clash)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-code-404, url-routing

#### Problem

I have two controllers: `RequestsController` and `ServicesController`. Both contain `Index` actions.

When I browse to `/Requests`, it automatically runs the `Index` action, but for `/Services` or `/Services/`, it gives an HTTP 404 without even running the `Index` action.

#### Background

The route configuration is stock. The project also contains various classes under a top-level directory called *Services*:

[image]

#### Troubleshooting

The problem seems to be related to some sort of clash in naming between `ServicesController` and the top-level `Services` folder.

- I can still access `/Services/Index` without a problem.
- Debugging confirms that the `Index` method is being run for `Requests` but not `Services` when I don't specify the action name in the URL.
- Renaming or removing the top-level *Services* folder causes the problem to stop happening.

Comment: interesting one...there's nothing wrong with you controllers, actions or your routes

Comment: @Leo, yeah; I just tried setting up the described configuration in isolation, and the problem didn't occur, so it looks like it's caused by a factor not covered in the above description. I'm working on it!

Comment: Installed Glimpse? It will show you what the routing is mapping to.

Comment: @TiesonT., I tried installing it, but the Glimpse HUD doesn't show when I navigate to `/Services`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see. That's a common issue when you have a controller with the same name as a folder inside the root directory. Assuming that none of the files inside the `Services` folder are mapped by the `StaticFilesHandler` I think you can simply tell the routing system to map all "services" routes to the `ServicesController` by setting the `RouteExistingFiles` to `true`...

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

#### Update

I completely ignore the `Content` folder. You will need to prevent requests to the "Content" folder (or any other folder containing static files such as the Scripts folder) from going through the routing pipeline by explicitly specifying it BEFORE your routing-mapping logic...

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("FOLDER_NAME/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: This did solve the problem, but it also seemed to disable access to server-side content such as CSS and JS files.

Comment: @Sam true. You will need to add the respective ignore directives to your content files. I'll update my answer in a minute

Comment: Thanks for your update! Putting it before the route made requests for controller actions redirect to the default route, which then produced a 404. Putting it after the route didn't seem to fix the problem caused by `RouteExistingFiles`.

Comment: I think this last problem was caused by the curly braces in your URL pattern. Removing them fixed the problem for the files under *Content*. I also needed to add a similar line for the *Scripts* folder.

Comment: @Sam I was just making a bit more clear...glad you got it working by yourself